PC didn't boot into either windows or Ubuntu, how to fix?
It is a lenovo thinkpad L440, 8gig ram, 500HDD. Running Windows 10 before. I was learning web development on the Odin project. One requirement is to install Linux. So, I want both OS on the PC. I followed all the tutorial and after everything is done. Asked to restart, then removed the USB drive, and press enter.
When the pc restart and when it reached the splash screen, it immediately displayed a black screen with the text "Reset System" at the top left corner of the screen, and after like 2 second it will restart again. It has been doing like that ever since. I have troubleshooting since but no luck.
I am using the same PC to post this issue because I don't have any other one, just one pc, one flash drive. What I did was that, I inserted the flash drive again and booted from it, that is the Ubuntu ISO. On getting to the installation page, I chose try ubuntu, that is why I have been able to post here.
I have followed the instruction on this page;
after running the boot repair application, here is the report .
Please, help me look into it and provide me solution. Thank
OS Version:

Windows 10
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Installed)


What version of Ubuntu did you install?

Thank for your help.
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Your machine has a legacy install Windows/msdos disk (probably an upgrade from the original Windows 7). The Ubuntu install you did tried to make an efi partition in a logical partition (the only type left after the limit of 4 primaries). Change your machine settings to prefer legacy, and do the install again.  Probably clean up the unwanted efI at least, the root may be reformatted.
